# What is the volume of the liquid when the mass is 2.00 grams?

Tags: volume

So I have to find the volume of an unspecified liquid when the mass is 2.00 grams. I am given the following information:

Volume = 1.00 mL which is equal to Mass = 0.81 g

This is all I'm given and I'm not sure which formula to use to get the correct answer.

Some pointers in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0.81g$ corresponds to $1.00 ml$

So $1g$ corresponds to $\frac{1}{0.81} ml$

So $2g$ corresponds to $\frac{2}{0.81}ml\approx 2.469135802 \ ml$

Comment: Huh. I can't believe I didn't think of that... Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome :)